# Select specific set of data on Crystal Report XI

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I don't think this is a very good title, but I couldn't think of anything else.
Anyway, I currently have two values `StartingOdo` and `EndingOdo` whose values are declared in the formula field, `RT`.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Numbervar StartingOdo;
Numbervar EndingOdo;
Numbervar OOBillCount;
Numbervar OOBillMiles;
Numbervar COBillCount;
Numbervar COBillMiles;
dateVar sReadTime;
dateVar eReadTime; 

if StartingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then
StartingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING};
if StartingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then 
sReadTime := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ACTIVE_DATE};
if EndingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then
EndingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING};
if EndingOdo = 0 and {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} > 0 then 
eReadTime := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ACTIVE_DATE};
if StartingOdo > 0 and EndingOdo > 0 then
if Endingodo < {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} and sReadTime < eReadTime then
EndingOdo := {VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING} ;
```

As you can see `StartingOdo`is declared as the very first field it finds, which is fine. The problem is where `EndingOdo`is being declared.
What I am hoping to accomplish is that `EndingOdo`be set to the very last value and not the greatest. The reason why this is a problem is because sometimes the values reporting in can be incorrect.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you be more specific? what do you mean by very last value and not the gratest?

Comment: Latest entry based off of timestamp so esentially I want ending odo to select the VW_RPT_NUT_TRUCK.ODO_READING based off of what the greatest timestamp was so ACTIVE_DATE and not the MAX value.